# How to prevent large strings from being updated to firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vue.js with vuetify on a very simple **Firebase** database with user authentication.

I have a field called `notes` and I never want a user to submit more than 2,000 characters. I know I can use `this.userInfo.notes.substring(0, 2000)` but I think that is on the client, and I think it should  be done on the server side.

I thought that all firebase apps would restrict the maxlength for updates, but I couldn't find examples.

I see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata but not sure how to use.

**Snippet**

```
updateDatabase () {
  database.ref('users').child(currentUserId).update({
    notes: this.userInfo.notes || '',
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user does enter more than 2000 characters? I think this is very well client-side logic and should first and foremost be handled on the client side. Only if you are really concerned about somebody circumventing your client side logic for this, you should also handle it on the server side as well. Use a `<textarea maxlength="2000">` for starters and then work from there.

Comment: Thanks... if >2000, I'll just truncate it the string.... I'm also using https://quilljs.com/ and there are client side solutions for that as well.  I do want to have all field updates restricted by length, textarea, input type=text, and quill. - I'm under the *impression* that client side solutions are easily by-passed (or perhaps I'm worrying about nothing). I will put max length on the fields I can... thanks, Rob

Answer (score 3):

For server-side validation you use Firebase's security rules. A simple string length filter would look something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "notes": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll give that a try.... Will this trigger an error message, or just truncate the string to 2000 characters and insert into Firebase database...

Comment: It will give an error message `permission denied`. For the best user experience you should also validate the same condition in the client, and give a more meaningful message (and refuse to send).